# group theory related modulo proof

Tags: group-theory

let $n$ be natural number $>1$. define  $[a] = \{b \in  Z :a \pmod n = b\}$ and $Z_{n}  = \{[x]:x \in Z\} $

define $[a] + [b] = [a+b]$ if $[x] = [y]$ , $[z] = [w]$,

prove $[x]+[z]=[y]+[w]$

don't know what it is asking of me

and the previous question is to prove that $Z_{n} = \{[0],[1]...[n+1]\}$ just in case it contains some sort of hint

Comment: Your definition of $[a]$ should be $[a] =\{b \in \mathbb{Z} \colon a \equiv b \pmod{n}\}$

Comment: yes it is . can you help me prove that Zn={[0],[1]...[n+1]}? I don't see what needs to be proved.

Answer (score 1):

The question is asking you to show that this notion of addition is *well-defined*. That is, the act of addition doesn't depend on what representation of the object you use. So for example, we have that (say, $n = 10$)

$$[2] = [22]$$
and $$[3] = [-7]$$
but how do we know that $$[2] + [3] = [22] + [-7] ?$$
After all, just going from the definition, the thing on the left is $[5]$ while the thing on the right is $[15]$. But happily, we can show that $[5] = [15]$ in any number of ways - element chasing is the easiest.

So, as far as what you need to prove: You should start with any two representatives of the classes you're adding (such as $2$ and $22$) and prove that the sets you get out of the $+$ operation are the same for these two representatives.